# d3js enter is not a function issue

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am new to d3js library. I try to drow Afrika continent contours and I have following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>geoPath measures</title>
</head>

<body>
<svg id="my_dataviz" width="400" height="300"></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var svg = d3.select('#my_dataviz');
  var projection = d3.geoMercator().center([0, 5]);
  var geoGenerator = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

  function update(geojson) {
    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(geojson.features)
      .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr('d', geoGenerator);
  }

  d3.json('africa.json', function(err, json) {
    update(json)
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: svg.append(...).selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a function
```

What is the issue? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The most likely cause of the error is probably that geojson.features is not an array. Can you log it and confirm it is?

Comment: Yep Andrew, this was an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [map data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson/master/continents/africa.json) is `topoJson` but you are treating it as `geoJson`.  So as @AndrewReid pointed out there is no `.features` property in it.

You can use [topoJson.js](https://github.com/topojson/topojson) to convert it:

```html
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <head>
    <title>geoPath measures</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg id="my_dataviz" width="1000" height="1000"></svg>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var svg = d3.select('#my_dataviz');
      var projection = d3.geoMercator().center([0, 5]);
      var geoGenerator = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

      function update(someTopoJson) {
      
        let geojson = topojson.feature(
          someTopoJson,
          someTopoJson.objects.continent_Africa_subunits
        );

        svg
          .append('g')
          .selectAll('path')
          .data(geojson.features)
          .enter()
          .append('path')
          .attr('d', geoGenerator)
          .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
      }

      d3.json(
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson/master/continents/africa.json',
        function (err, json) {
          update(json);
        }
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```